# Confusion regarding * operator in regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

I know * operator means any number occurances of the preceding character/s.

So an expression ab* would generate strings like "ab", "abab " etc. But it also generates the string "a" and I don't get this logic.
Is it something that the * operator considers only 1 character preceding to it for the operation. So with this logic * operation is applied only on 'b' in the mentioned example, and b is repeated 0 times so the resulting string "a" is generated. Please help.

Edit : ab* would not generate strings like "abab " like I mentioned above. It generates only strings like ab, abb, abbb etc

Comment: `So an expression ab* would generate strings like "ab", "abab " etc.` ... no it wouldn't.  It would generate things like `ab`, `abb`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So an expression `ab*` would generate strings like "ab", "abab " etc

That's not correct. `ab*` matches only `a`, `ab`, `abb`, `abbb`, `abbbb`, ...

> Is it something that the * operator considers only 1 character preceding to it

Exactly.

If you want to apply `*` to `ab`, then you have to group it: `(ab)*`

Answer (score 2):

> I know * operator means any number occurances of the preceding character/s.

The `*` operator means 0 or more occurrences of the preceding *expression*. In your case the expression before `*` is `b` (since in regexp each char is an expression). So `ab*` will match

```
a (0 "b" expressions)
ab (1 "b" expressions)
abbb (2 "b" expressions)
abab (1 "b" expressions followed by extra "ab", but note that `^ab*$` will not match `abab` since it is contained to the start/end of line.)
```

If you want to match `ab` zero or more times you have to handle `ab` as an expression, by using parenthesis like so `(ab)*`.

This part of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) explains it better than me.